# Fixing my 'Responsive' design

Tags: html, css, tumblr

On my website, [kylesethgray.com](http://kylesethgray.com/), I have made a somewhat 'responsive design'. Everything seems fine except two things:

1. If i have a list, be it `<ul>` or `<ol>`, the bullets get cut off when the browser window is shortened horizontally
2. For some reason, when doing the same thing to imitate a mobile browser, a horizontal scrollbar appears, and scrolls to the right, even though there isn't anything there.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: 1. Use `list-style-position: inside` 2. there is a youtube video which takes space

Comment: I took off the `padding: 0` on the `ul, ol` and it fixed itself, also the youtube video is causing the overflow, but It all looks fine on a mobile device, doesn't matter about a tiny browser window, its not a perfect mobile screen size indicator

Comment: about number 2: Even on the [second page](http://kylesethgray.com/page/2) it still has that scroll gap.


I'll try taking off the padding.

Comment: That's because there is an element `#pagination` which takes space... Just inspect the DOM and find the culprit(s).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the YouTube embed is breaking your layout, try this CSS:

`.video iframe { width: 100% }`

Also you should consider to use a framework for responsive design like [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or [Columnal](http://www.columnal.com/)

Comment: With that in place, even on my [second page](http://kylesethgray.com/page/2) the scroll bar still appears. I can't figure out what element is making it scroll...

Comment: [This page](http://kylesethgray.com/page/2) have no horizontal scroll for me

Comment: I fixed it now. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719203/fixing-my-responsive-design/15719301?noredirect=1#comment22328047_15719203